# Return types in the block are not implicitly convertible

Tags: c#, delegates, higher-order-functions

Hello i am trying to implement my own higher-order extensions but i can not understand why the aggregate (fold) gives the following error :

Error:

`Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate`
 `type because some of 
 the< return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate 
 return type.`

I do not understand why it says the return types don't match.I use as a `seed` a `List<object>` and in the `Fold` for every element i add the element to the list and return the `List<Object>`.

**Extension class:**

```
public static class HOrder
{
    public static IEnumerable<U> Map<T,U>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, Func<T, U> transform)
    {
        var map = collection.Select(transform);
        return map;
    }
    public static TAccumulate Fold<TAccumulate,TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource>source,TAccumulate seed,Func<TAccumulate,TSource,TAccumulate>aggregate)
    {
        var fold = Enumerable.Aggregate(source, seed, aggregate);
        return fold;

    }
    internal static object Extractor(Node node)
    {
        object result;
        switch (node.Kind)
        {
            case Node.Discriminator.String: result = node.AsStirng.Value; break;

            case Node.Discriminator.Integer: result = node.AsInteger.Value; break;

            case Node.Discriminator.Array: result = 
                 HOrder.Fold<Node,List<object>>(
                        node.AsArray.Items, 
                        new List<object>(), 
                        (x, y) => { y.Add(Extractor(x)); return y; } //<--Error at return y
                        );
             break;

            default:throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

**P.S** : The error is highlighted on the `return y`.

Comment: But i am not saying something like if `T` ==`Y` then `List<T>== List<Y>` .The type is `List<object>` and i am not doing any type inference.It is crystal clear the signature. I just use a side-effect to add an item to an already existing list.

Comment: It's hard to help with an incomplete example. We need the `Node` type in order to reproduce this for ourselves. Could you either include `Node` or reduce the problem to something smaller using system types?

Comment: Sure i did not add it because it is a medium size chunk of code.I wanted to be concise and not overwhelm readers with too much data.

Comment: `return y` is expected to be of type `Node` as that is your `TAccumulate` argument, but `y` is of type `List<object>` since that is your `TSource` argument. Since the converter can't implicitly convert from `Node` to `List<object>` it yells loudly....

Comment: Look at the definition of the  aggregate Func<>: It's first two type arguments are Accumulator,Source. Your lambda is referencing them the other way around

Comment: Oh you are right i am sorry.I was not looking at the `Func` definition.I was looking at the `Fold` and it seemed right.

Comment: Change `(x, y) =>` to `(y, x) =>` and it should work. One reason why single letter variable names suck sometimes. Though... I'm surprised you weren't getting errors for the Add/Extractor calls. Actually... You have them reversed in your call to Fold<> as well. It should be `Fold<List<object>, Node>` since accumulate comes first and source second

Comment: Other than using your preferred names, what are the supposed advantages of just wrapping `Select` and `Aggregate` LINQ functions?

Comment: If you rely on type inference the second issue goes away (the reverse type arguments in the call to Fold) then it's a matter of fixing your lambda to match the Func signature. `HOrder.Fold(node.AsArray.Items, new List<object>(), (x, y) => { x.Add(Extractor(y)); return x; });` though I see no benefit of using this over Aggregate directly. What's more, since you've defined these as extensions, you can call them as such: `node.AsArray.Items.Fold(new List<object>(), (x, y) => { x.Add(Extractor(y)); return x; });`

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by switching the generic parameters from  `Fold<Node,List<object>>` to `Fold<List<object>>,Node>`.

Answer (score -1):

Btw, @pinkfloydx33's comment on the original question was my solution! I dislike single letter lambda variables!!

> Blockquote Change (x, y) => to (y, x) => and it should work. One reason why single letter variable names suck sometimes. Though... I'm surprised you weren't getting errors for the Add/Extractor calls. Actually... You have them reversed in your call to Fold<> as well. It should be Fold<List, Node> since accumulate comes first and source second – pinkfloydx33 Jun 18 '18 at 8:47